# Uninstalling an app I'm not sure how it was installed

Tags: apt, kubuntu, snap, foxitreader, discover-software-center

Kubuntu 21.10

Foxit Reader is unstable as hell on my PC so I want to remove it, but I don't remember and now can't find how it was installed in the first place so I can do it right. dpkg didn't list it, Discover doesn't list it, snap doesn't list it, apt remove doesn't find it.

Now I'm happy just to delete the folder in `/opt` and delete the task menu icon, but I'd like to do it properly. What might I have missed?

Comment: First run `sudo updatedb`. After that, what is the output of `locate foxit` and `locate Foxit`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How do I find the installation method of an application?

If `apt list --installed` or `snap list` doesn't list the package, then it means:

- You have installed it through some other Package Manager such as flatpak.
- You have compiled from the source code.

As far as I know, Foxit reader isn't available for Flatpak or snap. Nor it's [available for apt](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=foxit-reader+&searchon=names&suite=impish&section=all).

Usually, when someone wants to install a specific software they do:

- [Search Google - How to install Foxit reader on Ubuntu?](https://www.google.com/search?q=Foxit+Reader+Linux+flatpak+&sxsrf=APq-WBvGZtFOgl9Gn6ceqi8WYzWoXYX1xg%3A1643946024593&ei=KKD8YbHMI5_Bz7sPgrCi2AI&oq=Foxit+Reader+Ubuntu+Linux)
- Browse the Software Catalog of Gnome Software ([or snap store](https://snapcraft.io/store)).
- [Or search using `apt search foxit`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=foxit+&searchon=names&suite=impish&section=all).
- [Search for a Launchpad Personal Package Archive (PPA).](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas)

If we:

- [Search Google:- Install using the tar file.](https://www.google.com/search?q=Foxit+Reader+Linux+flatpak+&sxsrf=APq-WBvGZtFOgl9Gn6ceqi8WYzWoXYX1xg%3A1643946024593&ei=KKD8YbHMI5_Bz7sPgrCi2AI&oq=Foxit+Reader+Ubuntu+Linux)
- [Search Software Catalog:- We couldn't find anything for your search
  Foxit Reader.](https://snapcraft.io/search?q=Foxit+Reader+)
- [Apt search:- Sorry, your search gave no results](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=foxit+&searchon=names&suite=impish&section=all)
- [PPA:- Nope.](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=foxit+reader&show_inactive=on)

#### So what is the conclusion?

As in the above section of the answer, we saw that both `apt` or `snap` or even `flatpak` don't have the package Foxit Reader in their repositories. Moreover, many people Google everything up to find packages. **Which indicates you have compiled the package from the source.**

#### How do I remove Foxit Reader?

Just run the uninstaller and hope for the best. In the help center of Foxit Reader, they have given a [nice tutorial about the same](https://help.foxit.com/manuals/pdf-reader/foxit-reader-for-mac/en-us/2.2/Get_Started.html#Get_Started_Uninstall_Foxit_Reader).

> Double click the Uninstaller file in the Foxit Reader installation directory.

**N.B**: You can use the following commands to extract the directory:

```
gzip -d '<name of the tar file>'
tar xvf '<name of the uncompressed file>'
```

Replace `<name of the tar file>` with the exact name of the file.

**NOTE**: You can get the archive mentioned in the help center from [the official download page](https://www.foxit.com/downloads/pdf-reader-thanks.html?product=Foxit-Reader&platform=Linux-64-bit&version=&package_type=&language=English&formId=download-reader).

Answer (score 2):

### Install Foxit Reader

> *source: the offical website*

### For Linux

Choose one of the following methods to install Foxit Reader:

Extract the package you downloaded, double click the executable file, and then follow the step-by-step instructions in the Installation Wizard to install Foxit Reader on your computer.
Use the following Terminal command line:

a. Change the directory containing the downloaded file (used /tmp as the example):

```
# cd /tmp
```

b. Uncompress the executable file

```
# gzip -d 'FoxitReader_version_Setup.run.tar.gz'
```

c. Untar the .tar file

```
# tar xvf 'FoxitReader_version_Setup.run.tar'
```

d. Run the installer:

```
# ./'FoxitReader_version_Setup.run'
```

e. Follow the steps on the screen to complete the installation

### Uninstall Foxit Reader

---

Double click the Uninstaller file in the Foxit Reader installation directory.

> Official website: https://help.foxit.com/manuals/pdf-reader/foxit-reader-for-mac/en-us/2.2/Get_Started.html